# Can a Directive be used to nest a content into the ng-template in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my project I want to nest my code into the ng-template dynamically with the use of Directive. Is there any way to do it in Angular

I am having a code like this

```
<button> Click Me </button>
```

If I use a directive (custDir) like this

```
<button custDir> Click Me </button>
```

Angular should render like this

```
<ng-template>
    <button> Click Me </button>
</ng-template>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the button text, you need to use ng-content

In your directive:

```
<ng-template>
    <button> <ng-content></ng-content><!--This will get replaced with "Click Me" -->  </button>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I need to wrap the whole element inside the ng-template not only 'Click Me'. Can we do like this?

Comment: yes whatever is put in ng-content, even the html tag, should get wrapped